# Imac turn off the screen: where is the eject button to use in the shortcut?

Tags: screen, shortcut, eject

I have a small wireless keyboard. Where can I find the eject button to turn screen off??

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. What is the model and make of your wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

At the back of the screen. It's the same as the power button. There may be a setting to make this work.